# setCookie() in Nuxt3 server

Tags: cookies, vuejs3, setcookie, nuxt3, data-synchronization

This is the code in /server/api of my Nuxt3 project.

```
// server/api/getevents.ts
export default defineEventHandler(async (req) => {
    setCookie(req, 'Token', "token here...")
    const response = await $fetch("localhost:3001/events", {method: 'post'})
    return response
})
```

The issue I am facing is that `setCookie()` doesn't work cuz of `return response` code block in the code above. If I don't write `return response`, `setCookie()` works well. But I need to return the response to the client. I guess this is related to the SSR but cannot find the solution yet. please help me.

I tried to remove `return response` code. Then it worked.
But I need that code and if I use it `setCookie()` doesn't work.